# How do I default to a single element array?

Tags: arrays, groovy

Consider this:

```
alwaysBeArr = someFunc()
alwaysBeArr.each {
    echo "${it.dump()}"
}
```

Sometimes someFunc() returns a list of strings sometimes just one string. If it only returns one string ".each{}" treats it like an arr of chars.

Is there a groovy way of making sure this is a single element array even if it only gets back a single string?

Comment: If you have a saying in `someFunc()`, then fix it there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the `flatten()` method. We create a list with the result (in either case), then flatten:

```
def someFunc = { ->
    (System.currentTimeMillis() % 2) ? 'mozart' : ['bach', 'beethoven', 'brahms'] 
}

def alwaysBeArr = [someFunc()].flatten()

alwaysBeArr.each { println it }
```